# Have Arrayformula({Sheet1,Sheet2}) result in same colums ? (not side by side)

Tags: google-sheets

question about GoogleSpreadsheets.

```
Arrayformula({Sheet1,Sheet2})
```

this formula works for me cause it MERGES the content of the two sheets into a 3rd sheet (both sheets and destination sheet have the same structure/columnsCount)

BUT my problem is :
 -  **everything taken from Sheet1 is put on columns A to W** (the formula is indeed in cell A1)
 - **everything from Sheet2 is put in columns X to AT** !

Is there a way to display first all the content of Sheet1 and THEN **right-under it** add all the lines from Sheet2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'stack' vertically, you need to use a semi-colon

```
=Arrayformula({Sheet1; Sheet2})
```

Note that his will also import blank rows. So to filter those out you may need to wrap a query() around it.

```
=QUERY (Arrayformula({Sheet1; Sheet2}), "where Col1 <> '' ")
```

or if the first col is numerical

```
=QUERY (Arrayformula({Sheet1; Sheet2}), "where Col1 is not null ")
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I could not figure out the , and ; difference
Actually it seems my content WAS appearing but there was so many blank lines inbetween (999) that i could not imagine my other lines where somewhere down-there ! i was thinking that the 2nd sheet importation did not work.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Can I bother you to 'accept' my answer ?